# chemical reaction that causes electrolysis of salt water without adding electric current

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

I am producing hydrogen using house hold items in a capacitor like arrangement in salt water. I assume this is chemical electrolysis. The apparatus produces gas for many weeks that burns orange. Its easily assembled from stuff you would normally find in the trash. Do I have something of interest, or is this common chemistry?

Comment: The capacitor is providing electric charge, right?  Electrolysis should occur.

Comment: Although what you've done is really cool, from a purely technical perspective you've essentially re-invented the wheel. This is simple hydrolysis in which you use a capacitor as the source of current rather than a battery or some other power supply. Eventually you have to re-charge the capacitor, though again that's an impressive setup if it really maintains a flame for weeks at a time. Maybe you can market it as a candle of sorts?

Comment: OP is not using a capacitor.  He is describing the electrode (capacitor plate like) arrangement of his electrolysis apparatus.  He is likely creating O2, H2 and some Cl2 by electrolysis.  This is well researched and large quantities can be dangerous if exploded.